# zend is the db adapter created before or after bootstraping

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db

I'm trying to set up a service locator during bootstrapping 
all of these services rely on the database Zend_Db and each service has the required data mappers injected on creation.

looks a little something like this:

```
$alertService = new WORK_Alert_Service_Service(array("AlertMapper" => new Model_Alert_Mapper(), 
                                                          "AlertUserSubscriptionMapper" => new Model_Alert_User_Subscription_Mapper()));

    $emailerService = new WORK_Emailer_Service_Service(
        array("AccountMapper" => new Model_Emailer_Email_Account_Mapper()));

    $encryptionService = new WORK_Encryption_Service_Service();

    $services = array( 
        $alertService,
        $emailerService,
        $encryptionService
    );

    WORK_ServiceLocator::regiserServices($services);
```

So what i discovered is that i get the following error

> problemNo adapter found for Model_Emailer_DbTable_EmailAccounts

the reason this is happening for the emailer service but not the alert service is that
the emailer service connects to the db and gets all the available email accounts and stores them in the object for later use on construction (maintains the mapper object so that the account list can be manipulated / cleared and reset if required).

Does the Zend_Db adapter get created after the bootstrapping process ?
if so is it possible to move this forward ?

could i get around this by moving these to the bootstrap files for individual modules ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm trying to set up a service locator during bootstrapping

I'm assuming then that the above code appears in a bootstrap `_init*` method. If so, simply place this at the start of your method

```
protected function _initServices()
{
    $this->bootstrap('db');

    // and the rest
```

See http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.application.theory-of-operation.html#zend.application.theory-of-operation.bootstrap.dependency-tracking

Comment: this was exactly what i needed thank you.
and yes you were right in an _init method.
Do the _init Methods get executed in order as they are written in the bootstrap ?

Comment: It uses [`get_class_methods()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class-methods.php) internally which appears to return them in order of declaration. I'm not sure how it integrates this order with the resource plugins, hence the need to bootstrap dependencies